# Wrong dimension for linear matrix inequalities in control

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, control-theory, linear-matrix-inequality

Given a linear system with A matrix 4x4 and B matrix having 2 columns 4 rows I want to solve a LMI problem to determine the K that stabilize the linear system.

\begin{equation}
\dot{x} = Ax + Bu\\
u = -Kx
\end{equation}

and said $A-BK$ the closed loop dynamics the Lyapunov functions led us to this inequality.
\begin{equation}
(A - BK)^T P + P (A - BK) < 0
\end{equation}
I do all the calculations and the multiply by $P^{-1}$ and P both sides of the inequality and making the position $S = P^{-1}$, $L=K*P^{-1}$. I get:
\begin{equation}
S \cdot A' + A \cdot S + L' \cdot B + B \cdot L \leq 0
\end{equation}
Where $S$ and $L$ are my unknowns, the problem is that i have no idea which dimension I should set the L, I tried $2x2, 4x2, 2x4$ But given the dimension of $B$ it's always not doable. Do you know which is the problem?

Comment: The matrix $L$ has the same dimensions as $K$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if there's a mistake in your post. Are you trying to compute the following?

$$
\mathbf{P}^{-1}\left[
\left(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{B}\mathbf{K}\right)^{\top}\mathbf{P}+
\mathbf{P}\left(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{B}\mathbf{K}\right)
\right]\mathbf{P}^{-1}
=
\mathbf{P}^{-1}\mathbf{A}^{\top}+
\mathbf{A}\mathbf{P}^{-1}-
\mathbf{P}^{-1}\mathbf{K}^{\top}\mathbf{B}^{\top}-
\mathbf{B}\mathbf{K}\mathbf{P}^{-1}
$$

If this is the case, you forgot to transpose the matrix $\mathbf{B}$ in the third term and the size of $\mathbf{L}$ should be $2\times 4$.